# Move a static range of data to another sheet while getting other fields into columns next to the destination (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The challenge has been getting cell values from the document header together with a range underneath this header to Sheet2, having it as a table, so that later, I can filter, update and delete records via scripts.

So far, I got the below code copying what's within the range underneath the header:

```
function copyrange() { 
  var sourceSheet = 'NewItem';
  var destinationSheet = 'DW';

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var LastRowSource = sheet.getLastRow();
  var LastColumnSource = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var values = sheet.getRange(11,1,LastRowSource,LastColumnSource).getValues();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet); 
  var data = []; 
  var j =[]; 
  //var itemheader = [sheet.getRange("C4:4").getValues(),sheet.getRange("A3:3").getValues(),sheet.getRange("i3:3").getValues(),sheet.getRange("i4:4").getValues(),sheet.getRange("c5:5").getValues(),sheet.getRange("e5:e").getValues(),sheet.getRange("i5:5").getValues(),
    //            sheet.getRange("C7:7").getValues(),sheet.getRange("c8:8").getValues(),sheet.getRange("c9:9").getValues(),sheet.getRange("e7:7").getValues(),sheet.getRange("e8:8").getValues(),sheet.getRange("i7:7").getValues(),sheet.getRange("i8:8").getValues(),
      //          sheet.getRange("e9:9").getValues()];

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if ( values[i][0] != '') { 
      data.push(values[i]);
      //sheet.deleteRow(i+1)
    } 
  } 
  //Copy data array to destination sheet 
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,17,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Now, getting different cell values from the header into a row and copying it to Sheet2 as many times/rows as there is in the range copied by the above script seems impossible to me.

Here is a link to a practical example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GlD_VIOFHj7PGfCCnfVZqdZbE22aVoUw91BSCZecsRc/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot for your help. Believe me, I've hit my head against the wall enough with this one before I turn to you guys!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about the input and output you expect. Can you explain about your shared Spreadsheet? Is your shared Spreadsheet the sample input situation? If it's so, can you provide the sample output you expect?

Comment: Hello @Tanaike! Your English is fine.
I have moved the header info to the DW sheet manually so you can see the expected result. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm your updated Spreadsheet. From the updated Spreadsheet, I could understand that the values of `A1:T10` are added to the row value of `A12:T`. In this case, you have already known the required cells in `A1:T10`. So at first, you retrieve the values from them, and you add the retrieved values to the row value of `A12:T`. How about this?

Comment: I see your approach. I could have an arrayformula setup and hide those columns, so that the users can see the sheet as it is.
Wouldn't there be a way of adding A1:T10 data straight to the DW sheet via script, next to the data from A12:T?

Comment: Hello, is now the Sheet different? I can't see any daya in DW at A12:T.

Comment: Just checked! There are 2 rows of data, simulating the data coming from the NewItem sheet, @Jescanellas!